# I can't get the right graph on pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to get the graph, which shows data from this table:

[image]

This is what I get from my code:

[image]

Where is my mistakes and how can I get specific value to a specific year?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

This is the original graph, which I get the first time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bCoN.png)

What I want, is to get the graph, where x axis is years and Y axis is lap times, and I want them both to be from the lowest to the highest. And then to have specific points on the graph, where 2004 is 1:18.233, 2009 is 1:18.530 etc.

Edit:

So this is what I did so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mysql.connector as CN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cir = pd.read_csv('circuits.csv')
races = pd.read_csv('races.csv')
qua = pd.read_csv('qualifying.csv')

racescir = pd.merge(cir, races, how='inner', left_on = 'circuitId', right_on = 'circuitId')

res = pd.merge(racescir, qua, how = 'inner', left_on = 'raceId', right_on = 'raceId')

res_si = res[res['circuitId'] == 9]

res_si_gro = res_si.groupby(['year'])['q1'].min()

fig, gr = plt.subplots()
gr.plot(res_si_gro)
plt.show()
```

And this is how I get my graph.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Picture is a very poor format for exchanging textual data (copy paste it instead). What is the type of your data, it looks like string but you are using plot function that is generally for numericall data?

Comment: I don't get your edit, is it not what is in your last figure ?

Comment: I want the Y axis (lap times) going from the lowest to the highest and then the graph should be more twisting

Comment: Do you mind to copy paste your data in order to allow other users to reproduce your input while not having to re encode data by hands (see my first comment)

Comment: Edited one more time. Hope it's more clear, I'm still new here, so kind of difficult so far

Answer (score 0):

This will show the data points (red), and connect them with two different lines: with sorted values (green), and with sorted index - year (blue).

Note that it doesn't matter in which order you plot the **points**. Their locations will be same in each situation. A point is a pair of `year` and `value`, and it doesn't change when sorting. You can't change their locations on the graph without changing your data.

A line, however, goes through these points in order as they appear in your Series. So by sorting it you change the order of how the line goes through your points.

```py
fig, gr = plt.subplots()
gr.plot(res_si_gro.sort_values(), alpha=0.3, color='green')
gr.plot(res_si_gro.sort_index(), linewidth=3)
gr.scatter(res_si_gro.index, res_si_gro, color='red')  # data points
plt.show()
```

---

##### Example with my data:

[image: plot]

```py
np.random.seed(0)
n = 9
years = np.random.choice(np.arange(1990, 2020), n, replace=False)

res_si_gro = pd.Series(np.arange(n), index=years, name='q1')
res_si_gro.index.rename('year', inplace=True)
res_si_gro
```

```
year
1992    0
2018    1
2003    2
2000    3
2016    4
2014    5
2017    6
2001    7
2007    8
Name: q1, dtype: int64
```